# Element not visible Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, click, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl data from agoda.com. I want to filter all the reviews by language, english. When I do a count based on the selector, I get 1, however, when I try to click or wait for the element to be visible, the program throws the element not visible exception after the timeout.

This is the code I am trying so far

```
String url = "https://www.agoda.com/en-sg/resorts-world-sentosa-hard-rock-hotel/hotel/singapore-sg.html";
driver.get(url);
try {
    for (WebElement element: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'language-')]"))) {
        if (element.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("input")) {
            if (element.findElement(By.xpath("..")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("english")) {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
                element.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I see no elements with `id` that starts with `language-`. Clarify what element exactly you want to get.

Comment: I am referring to the Review language section in the reviews filter. language-1 is English's checkbox id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use following code:

```
// To find and click on required check-box
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[input[starts-with(@id, 'language-')]/span[text()='English']]"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to be sure from here what's wrong, especially without the actual copy-paste from the exception, but one cause for that is an element present but not currently visible. It might be suppressed or out of the viewport. If you open the page in a browser such as Chrome that supports a "developer" mode, you can view the element attributes to confirm or refute that.

Side notes:
• Post complete information about your problem with your question. What is the exact exception, its message, and a few lines of the stack trace?
• If possible, post the details of the web element from your "developer" view of it.
• Don't catch `Exception`, catch specific exceptions.
• Copy and paste code fragments rather than retyping them. If your actual code called `printlkn` then you have deeper problems.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I am sorry for the inconvenience. My code was a bit messy, so I just thought retyping would be better. Nevertheless, if I check `driver.findElements(By.id("language-1")).size()`, it gives me 1. But, it is getting clicked